# conditional statements not working in expression editor

Tags: ireport

I want to check current month to many condition as below.
so I take `TextField` ,edit its pattern to `MM` & in expression editor edit below code

```
new java.util.Date()>=4 && new java.util.Date() <= 7 ? "Q1" :  
new java.util.Date()>=8 && new java.util.Date() <=11  ? "Q2" : "Q3"
```

but it gives error

```
Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :      Source text : new java.util.Date()>=4 && new java.util.Date() <= 7 ? "Q1" : new java.util.Date()>=8 && new java.util.Date() <=11  ? "Q2" : "Q3" 
Setting up the file resolver..
```

but when I give expression like

```
new java.util.Date()== 4 ? "Q1" : "Q2"
```

It works fine.

Does iReport not able to resolve multiple conditions ? or should I give different `TextField` with single condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using calendar instead.

```
(Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.MONTH)>=3 && (Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.MONTH)>=6 ? "Q1" :
(Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.MONTH)>=7 && (Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.MONTH)>=10  ? "Q2" : "Q3"
```

Answer (score 2):

are you sure new java.util.Date() is just give you the month.

try this it will give you the moth
 
(new SimpleDateFormat("M")).format(new java.util.Date())

also you can use yyyy(year) or d(date) to check 
and Integer.parse(...month...) or Date.parse(...month...) maybe needed, if you don't have your Qs as integer or date.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try putting the expression in brackets like

(new java.util.Date()>=4 && new java.util.Date() <= 7 )? "Q1" : ( 
(new java.util.Date()>=8 && new java.util.Date() <=11 ) ? "Q2" : "Q3")

Comment: are you using exactly this expression "new java.util.Date()>=4" .because that i guess does not return months.So it would be helpful if you can paste the exact expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple condition like this

```
new java.util.Date() >= 4  ?
 "Q1" :
new java.util.Date() <= 7  ?
 "Q2" :  
new java.util.Date() >= 8  ?
 "Q3" :
 "Q4"
```